# Node.js alternative to mysqli_fetch_array()?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, express

```
<?php
        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', "root", "", "test");
        if(!$connect){
            die(mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
            <div class='article-div'>;
                <a href='articleviewer.php?id=$row[ID]' class='article-title'> . <?php $row['Title'] ?>. </a>;
            </div>;
        <?php }
        mysqli_close($connect);
    ?>
```

So I have this code in PHP, which is self-explanatory really. It fetches the MySQL in an array and keeps printing divs for each article while posting the article's title.How do I do this in node.js with express? I have the "mysql" module installed. So what's the node equivalent to the mysqli_fetch_array()?

Comment: read the documentation for `mysql` module. If you have trouble implementing some specific method, that'd be a more appropriate question.

Comment: For a little more abstraction you can try kbex.js: http://knexjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As npm's [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries) module documentation says, you simply need to make a query like:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = "David"', function (error, results, fields) {
    // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query 
    // results will contain the results of the query 
    // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any) 
});
```

You can then iterate over `results` via simple loop.
Note: In the beginning of the documentation, there is an explanation about how to connect to the database and configure it. Read that first :)

Comment: Lol yea, I figured it out after I posted the question. I totally forgot to read the documentation, I just googled and found nothing so came here. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) or [node-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql) modules:

```
npm install -g mysql
```

or

```
npm install -g node-mysql
```

Below is example usage (assuming there is a table named `example_table` with columns `ID`, `FileName` and `FileSize` in database `node_dev`):

```
var mysql = require('mysql'),
qid = '1'; // example ID

var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'DATABASE_USER_HERE',
  password : 'DATABASE_PASSWORD_HERE',
  database : 'node_dev'
});

/* SQL */
db.connect();
db.query('SELECT * FROM `example_table` WHERE RowID=?', [qid], function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
      // either of those two will do:
      console.log(rows[i].FileName, rows[i].FileSize); 
      console.log(rows[i]['FileName'], rows[i]['FileSize']);
    }
  }
});
db.end();
/* SQL */
```

You'ill probably (most of the time) want to write simple middleware/microservices with other node modules such as express, http/https, Oauth2 which will monitor for requests, catch parameters and send some output parsed as JSON or something.